# Remove zero-width characters from URLs in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, unicode

We have sent out a link which contains zero-width characters.

The URL's are encoded as follows:

```
/post%EF%BB%BF
```

How do I get nginx to remove these characters from the path? We would like to do this for all URLs, not just the example above.

Comment: Can you explain with an example what you expect? Should `/post%EF%BB%BF` become `/post`

Comment: Exactly that @Tar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *regular expression*, but the percent encoded characters will be represented as hex characters:

For example:

```
rewrite ^(.*)[\xef\xbb\xbf](.*)$ $1$2 permanent;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: Wonderful. I was trying to phrase the question for open-ended possible answers, and you answered with hex-encoding, exactly what I needed - thanks.